# Selenium WebDriver - StaleElementReferenceException that shouldn't be happening

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm trying out some scripts in Internet Explorer that were developed against Chrome originally (and that work great there), and finding that StaleElementReferenceExceptions seem to be the norm. Apparently this is because IE is so much slower?

It's my understanding that these Exceptions happen when you find a WebElement, and then the DOM changes, and then you try to do something to that WebElement, which confuses Selenium because the page has now changed and the references in the WebElement are no longer valid. If that's why StaleElementReferenceExceptions occur, then I don't know why I'm seeing this one.

I have a new window with a flash player in it, and after the flash player plays its video, I try to get some parameters out of the object. The page source looks a bit like this:

```
<object id="flashContent" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="flashContent" data="[redacted]" style="visibility: visible;">
    <param name="scale" value="noscale">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="">
    <param name="SeamlessTabbing" value="false">
    <param name="flashvars" value="[redacted]">
</object>
```

I am interested in reading the value of the flashvars param, so I have the following code:

```
text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("object#flashContent param[name='flashvars']")).getAttribute("value");
```

So I can't lessen the time between finding the param WebElement and getting its attribute any more than I already have, it seems, and yet getAttribute is throwing a StaleElementReferenceException every time. I've opened up the page source and watched the window - nothing is changing, as far as I can see. I tried catching the Exception for a certain period and just retrying in the hopes that I'd hit a time when the DOM was quiet and the WebElement was stable, but the following code helped me not at all:

```
    timer.start();
    while (true) {
        try {
            text = getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("object#flashContent param[name='flashvars']"))
                    .getAttribute("value");
            break;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            if (timer.getElapsedSeconds() >= 20) {
                debug("getAttribute is borked, throwing up...");
                throw e;
            } else {
                debug("getAttribute failed again but we're still trying after " + timer.getElapsedMilliseconds() + " milliseconds.");
            }
        }
    }
```

The above was designed to keep trying the find/getAttribute combo even if a StaleElementReferenceException was thrown, up until the time when a findElement call would usually time out (the implicit timeout of 20 seconds). The result of running it was that the findElement call succeeded and then the getAttribute call threw a StaleElementReferenceException every 50 milliseconds or so for the full 20 seconds; then it dumped out. During this time nothing whatsoever was happening on the page, at least not that I could see.

Any ideas as to why or how the WebElement could be stale in a situation like this?

**EDIT:** I have found a workaround that only applies to situations in which you are trying to get data from the page only (i.e., getting attributes or text from the page rather than clicking or sending keystrokes). My code already employs a library called [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to read the DOM into memory, which is very handy if you need to navigate the DOM and find information but want to avoid a series of low-performance Selenium find operations on the DOM itself. Using JSoup I was able to read in a static version of the DOM and extract the information I sought. However, this workaround will be useless if I ever find myself in a situation where I want to click or send keys, so I'd still like to know if there's any other option.

Comment: If the element is stale then repeatedly trying to use findElement() on it won't help much. How does this `<object>` look like *before* the video starts playing? Can you access it via Selenium without getting a StaleElementReferenceException?

Comment: @Dominik I'm not sure what you mean. I tried calling findElement().getAttribute() repeatedly. findElement() doesn't cause an error, getAttribute() does. findElement essentially gets a "fresh" version of the WebElement that should match the DOM at that point in time. My hope was that by calling it repeatedly over a period of time, I'd hit a moment where the DOM wasn't changing (assuming it really was) and thus the getAttribute() call would succeed because the WebElement would still be "fresh" when getAttribute() was called.

Comment: @Dominik As for the <object> tag, it doesn't change from the time when the page loads. As far as I can see, nothing in the page source changes before, during, or after the video plays. I don't call findElement().getAttribute() until after the video finishes anyway, so nothing is happening on the screen or in the page source when the StaleElementReferenceExceptions are getting thrown. Nothing that I can detect, at least.

Comment: Looking at your code, I also see nothing obviously wrong. I am not sure if your CSS locator is correct... so how about trying some other options. For example By.name("flashvars")...

Answer (score 0):

The StaleElementReferenceException is being caused by your code attempting to locate contents that no longer exist in the DOM. If you are accessing an old, static version of the DOM with JSoup then the contents of the DOM after the Flash video ends may no longer contain the flashvars param and/or its value attribute. Your initial approach is correct using the fastest code option:

```
  String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("object#flashContentparam[name='flashvars']")).getAttribute("value");
```

Wait for an element to be present in the DOM after the video ends that indicates the video has finished and then attempt to find the flashvars param and its value attribute. P.S.: Rarely the StaleElementReferenceException is caused by a rapid full or partial (AJAX) page refresh (<500 ms), usually it is an algorithmic problem.